# Why pipe equals doesn't work with tap in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, reference, functional-programming, iterator

If I modify an array inside `.tap` context, the modified version will be returned:

```
states = [:a, :b].tap do |sts|
  sts << :c
end

puts states # [:a, :b, :c]
```

But if I modify it with `|=`, it returns the same object:

```
states = [:a, :b].tap do |sts|
  [[:a, :c], [:b, :d]].each do |type|
    sts |= type
  end

  puts sts.inspect # [:a, :b, :c, :d]
end

puts states.inspect # [:a, :b]
```

Could point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why is that?

Simple, because you don't change the original `sts`. You instead create **a new array** (from the `|=` operator) and make `sts` point to that new array. Of course, as soon as `tap` block returns, this temp array is lost forever.

---

In case you didn't know,

```
sts |= type
```

is a shortcut for

```
sts = sts | type
```

Answer (score 1):

From the documentation:

> **tap {|x| block } → obj**
>
> Yields self to the block, and then returns self. The primary purpose of this method is to “tap into” a method chain, in order to perform operations on intermediate results within the chain.

In first case you modify the array passed and so it's changed.

In second case you just create a new array:

```
a = [1, 2] # => [1, 2]
b = a
b |= [3] 
a # => [1, 2]
b # => [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Why do I think what, the "noise"? How it helps demonstrate anything, I honestly wonder? [This is how I'd format it](https://pastebin.com/raw/xU8hcx7J), for example. Cleaner __and__ copy-pastable.

Comment: yeah, sorry if I wasn't clear. Obviously, I wasn't talking about the _code_. Just the noise :)